# Grade de dados com função 0 na restante PHP ou PHP+Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, banco-de-dados

Sou Programador Intermediário, e estou em um Impasse, Preciso exibir uns itens e o que faltar preciso que preencha com um modelo prefeito. Vamos lá explicar a Lógica ok?

Na Minha Tabela (vou usar exemplos ok?) ITENS, pode-se adicionar no máximo 20 ITENS(Até ae, tudo ok.).
Vamos supor que eu tenha 12 linhas na tabela ITENS  assim `[id]1[tipo_item]1`. Ou seja do `ID1` eu tenho 12 itens. Para completar o limite de 20 faltam 8, correto?

Agora preciso exibir assim:

Itens:
(id fica oculto nao precisa mostrar)(ou seja nao precisa puxar a variavel $id.)

```
[tipo1]  [tipo1]  [tipo1]  [tipo1]

[tipo1]  [tipo1]  [tipo1]  [tipo1]

[tipo1]  [tipo1]  [tipo1]  [tipo1]
```

(agora vem o problema)
os 8 "vazios restantes" precisava que mostrasse assim

```
[Vazio]  [Vazio]  [Vazio]  [Vazio]

[Vazio]  [Vazio]  [Vazio]  [Vazio]
```

Preciso que o código mostre todos os itens em grade, numa quantidade total por pagina que eu seleciono. mas preciso que ele faça uma conta tipo

```
20 - $quantidade de linhas
```

(no caso sobraram 8)
e esta que sobraram mostre um slot vazio.(ou num. x de imagens (exmplo vazio.png)(ou um texto (vazio)

Comment: Veja se esta solução em sql ajuda   http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/288300-consulta-sql-difcil/#entry1048056

Comment: É bom tirar metade dessas tags aí e se decidir se vai querer em PHP ou em JS. Estou respondendo em PHP, mas como você é um programador intermediário, acho que fica fácil adaptar pra JS se precisar.

Answer (score 4):

Como se trata de uma questão básica, procurei fazer um código bem didático:

```
<?php
   // Primeiro, vamos pegar um array com doze ítens para teste:
   $itens = array(
      'um', 'dois', 'tres', 'quatro', 'cinco', 'seis',
      'sete', 'oito', 'nove', 'dez',' onze', 'doze'
   );

   // depois, vamos contar o número de ítens 
   $qtdItens= count( $itens );

   // Aqui você define quantas colunas e linhas quer:
   $numColunas= 4;
   $numLinhas= 5;
   // O número de linhas poderia ser calculado automaticamente com facilidade,
   // baseado no número de colunas, mas vou me ater ao enunciado.

   for( $l = 0; $l < $numLinhas; $l++ ) {
      for( $c = 0; $c < $numColunas; $c++ ) {
         // vamos calcular de que ítem se trata:
         $itemAtual = $c + ( $l * $numColunas );

         // e decidir se imprimimos o [ítem] ou [Vazio]
         if( $itemAtual < $qtdItens) {
             echo '['.$itens[$itemAtual].']';
         } else {
             echo '[Vazio]';
         }
      }
      echo "\n"; //trocar por "<br>\n" se for exibir em página
   }
?>
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/oxKTwV)**.

Comment: Nossa, quanto tempo, obrigado feroz, achei essa conta perdida, e vim agradecer(mesmo já tendo resolvido na época). Abração!